# Create s3 buckets on AWS automatically

Tags: java, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

**[[Trying to create a domain spinner]]**

Manually i can create a bucket, upload some static html pages and get the domain name. 
the domain will be something like `BUCKET1.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`

Is there any way by which my html or Javascript can create these buckets automatically? Or any way to automate this process ?

My issue is to create a new Domain for every 10 users. And host the same HTML `index.html` and `404.html` pages into the buckets.

*Example:*

`BUCKET2.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`

`BUCKET3.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`

`BUCKET4.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: there is surely  a way, but that doesnt mean people here are to write code for you. Show us what you have done, if there is any problem, people here can help.

Comment: I understand it is not easy to write code for this. But if you can give me any tutorial link or and lead, i can learn.

Comment: it is very easy to write the code. i would rather suggest you to use JAVA  for this task at backend. Call dere API, read the documentation, hopefully you will come to know.

Comment: Much appreciation for you zubair :) 
I'l try this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can create it programmatically in java. Just use the AWS [SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) for java.

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("ACCES_KEY","SECRET_KEY")
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials );
amazonS3.createBucket("<BUCKET_NAME>");
```

You can also use AWS Lambda.

Comment: Thanks Noel, will try this :)